# How do I store textbox name reference in a Variable to later assign the value of that textbox to another variable

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an access project that I'm currently working and after a great amount of research I can't find a simple answer.  What I have is an unbound form with 10 textboxes. I need to add the same code to the double click event of each one of the boxes.  Basically I need to pass on the name of the active textbox and the value of such to another form.  Here is the sample code that illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
Textbox1 = date  (Is the active control) 

Dim x1, x2 as string
Dim x3 as date


x1 = Me.ActiveControl.name
x2 = "Me." & x1 & ".value"
x3 = x2 
msgbox x3
```

This give an error datatype mismatch as it gives me the string assigned to x2 (Me.Textbox1.Value) instead of the date.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a string variable and assigning it to the variable x2.

To get the actual value you need to pull it from the form's controls collection.

Try this instead:

`x2 = Me.Controls(x1).Value`

Comment: Thank you @dbmitch that's what I needed.  Perfect.